# How do you run code up until a certain line on Xcode?

Tags: xcode

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << argv[0];               //ONLY WANT TO RUN TILL HERE
    for(int x = 1; x < argc; x++)
    {
        string s(argv[x]);
        if(
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added and enabled a breakpoint on that line, but it still runs the whole program.

Screenshot of code:

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot. Maybe something is fishy with the breakpoint (you think?) you have set.

Comment: Your build failed due to an error (red dot).

Comment: Oh I thought that code would run until the breakpoint regardless if the code beyond the breakpoint works. I'm new at this lol

Comment: Fix the both the error and the warning because the warning is a bug that will make your program run incorrectly. You always want clean building code. Never accept any warnings. Once you start ignoring any warnings you will end up ignoring important warnings.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip Maddy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the errors in your code. The line with the red dot next to it has a syntax error that needs to be solved. Once you fix the error the program will run as desired.